# Replace string containing " with \"?

Tags: java, string

How can I replace string containing `"` with `\"` ?

`replace(""","\"")` is not working for me.

```
public static String replaceSpecialCharsForJson(String str){
    return str.replace("'","\'")
              .replace(":","\\:")
              .replace("\"","\"")
              .replace("\r", "\\r")
              .replace("\n", "\\n");
}
```

Comment: You have to escape the `\`: `"\\\""`

Comment: `"` is a special character so you have to use \ before it, like here  `\r` , `\n` .

Answer (score 5):

You can try with:

```
replace("\"","\\\"")
```

Since both `"` and `\` are *metacharacters*, you have to escape them with `\`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
replace("\"","\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Every slash as part of a string needs to be escaped. So if you want a string to look like `"\\"`, your code will have to contain `String s = "\\\\"`. Ugly but true.

The same goes for any other special character that might be interpreted. Quotes and colons inclusive.
This means `" \ " "` will look like `" \\ \" "` (Added spaces to make separate escapes more visible)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
str.replace("\"","\\\"")
```

So you escape the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You want to

- replace `"` *(properly escaped: `\"`)*
- with  `\"` *(properly escaped: `\\\"`)*.

The right call is:

```
replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way. I don't know how much this helpful in your scenario

```
String oldStr = String.valueOf('"');
String newStr = File.separator.concat(String.valueOf('"'));     
System.out.println(oldStr.replace(String.valueOf('"'),newStr));
```